# aggregate nested object on next position of parent object

Tags: nested, dataweave

I have a JSON object like this:

```
[
   {
      "questionText":"some text 1",
      "answerText":"some text"
   },
   {
      "questionText":"some text 2",
      "answerText":"some text"
   },
   {
      "questionText":"some text 3",
      "answerText":"some text",
      "disclosures":[
         {
            "questionText":"some text 4",
            "answerText":"some text"
         },
         {
            "questionText":"some text 5",
            "answerText":"some text"
         }
      ]
   },
   {
      "questionText":"some text 6",
      "answerText":"some text"
   },
   {
      "questionText":"some text 7",
      "answerText":"some text",
      "disclosures":[
         {
            "questionText":"some text 8",
            "answerText":"some text"
         }
      ]
   }
]
```

Where I must have to transform like this:

```
[
   {
      "questionText":"some text 1",
      "answerText":"some text"
   },
   {
      "questionText":"some text 2",
      "answerText":"some text"
   },
   {
      "questionText":"some text 3",
      "answerText":"some text"
   },
   {
      "questionText":"some text 4",
      "answerText":"some text"
   },
   {
      "questionText":"some text 5",
      "answerText":"some text"
   },
   {
      "questionText":"some text 6",
      "answerText":"some text"
   },
   {
      "questionText":"some text 7",
      "answerText":"some text"
   },
   {
      "questionText":"some text 8",
      "answerText":"some text"
   }
]
```

the keys of the nested object must be added on the next position of its parent. The values on its keys does not have numbers, so I cant ordenate then following the text.

How could I achieve this? Is it possible? Already tried to map like [this](https://help.mulesoft.com/s/question/0D52T00004nbMxBSAU/merging-of-nested-array-of-object-in-the-main-array) but it adds the array at the end of the JSON output

Comment: Can the nesting go to a deeper level? I mean can there be more `disclosures` inside a `disclosures` too?

Answer (score 3):

For each element of the main array we can separate the keys that have array values, and pluck the array from it, and concatenate to the keys that don't have array values. A couple of flatten operations flattens the nested arrays. This solution assumes that the order of the arrays is always at the end of each item.

```js
%dw 2.0
output application/json
---
flatten(payload flatMap (
    [($ filterObject ((value, key, index) -> 
        !(value is Array)
    ))]
    ++
    ($ filterObject  ((value, key, index) -> 
        value is Array
    ) pluck $)
))
```

Output:

```json
[
  {
    "questionText": "some text 1",
    "answerText": "some text"
  },
  {
    "questionText": "some text 2",
    "answerText": "some text"
  },
  {
    "questionText": "some text 3",
    "answerText": "some text"
  },
  {
    "questionText": "some text 4",
    "answerText": "some text"
  },
  {
    "questionText": "some text 5",
    "answerText": "some text"
  },
  {
    "questionText": "some text 6",
    "answerText": "some text"
  },
  {
    "questionText": "some text 7",
    "answerText": "some text"
  },
  {
    "questionText": "some text 8",
    "answerText": "some text"
  }
]
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to try using Map you can try this approach and further you can order resulting payload based on questionText

```
%dw 2.0
output application/json
---
(flatten(payload map (
    $.disclosures default []
)) ++ payload map (
    ($ - "disclosures")
))orderBy $.questionText
```

```
[
  {
    "questionText": "some text 1",
    "answerText": "some text"
  },
  {
    "questionText": "some text 2",
    "answerText": "some text"
  },
  {
    "questionText": "some text 3",
    "answerText": "some text"
  },
  {
    "questionText": "some text 4",
    "answerText": "some text"
  },
  {
    "questionText": "some text 5",
    "answerText": "some text"
  },
  {
    "questionText": "some text 6",
    "answerText": "some text"
  },
  {
    "questionText": "some text 7",
    "answerText": "some text"
  },
  {
    "questionText": "some text 8",
    "answerText": "some text"
  }
]
```

Comment: thanks for your answer! However, as explained in my question, the questionText actually does not have numbers, thus the script cannot rely on it

Answer (score 1):

If you know that the internal arrays will come in `disclosures` fields only you can use flatmap directly to get a flat structure. Below script will keep the order in which you are getting the elements in the payload and is short and simple.

```js
%dw 2.0
output application/json
---
payload flatMap (
    if($.disclosures is Null) $ 
    else ($ - "disclosures") >> $.disclosures //if there is a "disclosures" Array then move the items of this object at the top of disclosures Array and map to that
)
```

Answer (score 0):

In this case I'd like to use Descendants to select the data ([dw selectors](https://docs.mulesoft.com/dataweave/2.4/dataweave-selectors)). Grab all question and answer texts. Zip the two arrays so the results alternate and match up, `flatMap` and `reduce` the array items to create your desired object:

```
%dw 2.0
output application/json
import zip from dw::core::Arrays
var questions = payload..&questionText
var answers = payload..&answerText
---
(questions zip answers) 
    flatMap (QnA) -> 
        QnA reduce (item, acc={}) -> (
            acc ++ item
        )
```